# Limiting the number of objects an object can own in Laravel 5

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm trying to figure out if there is any way to limit the number of objects another object can own in Laravel 5.

For instance say you have an organization that has many users, but the plan their on limits the number of users they can have to 5, is there any built in function that would allow you to say that Organizations has many users and limit the  number of users to 5?

Comment: No there isn't any. I already did something similar and used [model events](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-events) to do the checking.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this is possible but just looking at the relationship types logically, I think it is not possible.

For example, we have `one to one`, `one to many`, and `many to many` relationship types. If this was possible, wouldn't we have a magic method like `hasMaximum5` or something to that effect ?

Ofcourse, this is possible to do in many ways using your application logic but not the Eloquent ORM I am afraid. Not sure if this is possible in other ORMs like Doctrine or ActiveRecord.

Comment: So I could probably create a function then saying hasMaximum($number) then huh? I just don't know where that function would go or what it would have to do to make it work